# when run old flutter project at get error so please me

Tags: android, flutter

BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 64

while run flutter project at getting error try many time in different code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.